# Maximum allowed size exceeded error when using IndexLocator

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am learning the locator in matplotlib. I wrote some code myself to observe their specific results. But there was an error with IndexLocator.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
plt.switch_backend('Agg')
ax=plt.subplot(2,2,1)
ax.set_xlim(-5,47)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mtick.IndexLocator(6,1))
print(ax.get_xticks())
```

The above code is abnormal. A Maximum allowed size exceeded error appeared in a python file.

Can someone give me some advice? Thanks.

Thanks Asmus. When I added the plot statement, the error disappeared. But the result is not as expected.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
plt.switch_backend('Agg')
ax=plt.subplot(2,2,1)
ax.set_xlim(-5,47)  
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mtick.IndexLocator(6,1))
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])  #newly added
print(ax.get_xticks())
```

What is printed is [1]. But I think the correct output should be [1. 7. 13. 19. 25. 31. 37.]

Comment: I've updated my answer below to explain what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually plot *something* in order to have some x limits which the tick locator can work with, adding e.g. a simple `ax.scatter([0,10],[0,10])` yields `[1. 7.]` for `print(ax.get_xticks())`.

**Update below:**

Actually, `[1]` is **completely expected** when you `plt.plot([1,2,3,4])`.

Why? Because your data points are: `[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]`, which means your `IndexLocator` places a single tick at `1`, but the next one (i.e. `1`+`6` = `7`) is never created since your x-axis only goes to 3!

You would need to plot at least `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` (i.e. have your x-axis go above `7`) to get a second tick!

Perhaps, you're rather looking for:  `ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-5,47,6))` ?

Comment: thank you for your reply. I made changes, but the result is still not as expected